# What is a good UX design for Android preference which requires both enable/disable and text input

Tags: android

Currently, I has added 2 new preferences in Android, in order to achieve

1. Enable/ disable stock email alert.
2. A text input, to specific which email to send to, when stock alert happened.

The design looks following

## When stock email alert is disabled

[image]

---

## When stock email alert is enabled

[image]

[image]

---

I was thinking, instead of providing 2 preferences, is there possible to provide only 1 preference, to achieve the above tasks with better UX?

I do believe less is more. However, I'm not sure what is a good UX, to help user to achieve the above 2 tasks.

Comment: Its good to leave it as it is now. Having it only as text input would be confusing as hell for some people. If you want, you could do a compromise and show the "Alert email" text field only when that feature is enabled instead of graying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two decisions that you want the user to make:

- I want to receive an Alert email
- I want to receive that Alert email in this email address

**The most clear approach is to keep both decisions separate, each in its own option**.

However, it is possible to combine both if you need to. If there is only an email address input, when empty it could either mean:

- The user wants to receive the email, but the address is not yet entered
- The user doesn't want to receive the email.

So you would need to use a placeholder that covers both situations. I'm attaching an example but you might find a better wording for your case.

[image]

Comment: It is possible to do so technically. However, it also doesn't clear for the user that, he needs to delete all text in the email input dialog box, in order to disable email alert feature.

Comment: You are right, as I said in the answer your current approach is more clear. Using a single option to both indicate a yes/no and a text input is not as clear as separating the two actions.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the approach for 'Less is more' but only when it does not compromise UX.

I don't recommend to use single 'Alert Email' just because it has following UX loophole

->Consider that user configured his/her email address, now later what if he want to just check which email is configured for the alert?

I would prefer keeping separate field for enabling 'Alert Email' and email address.
Further you can change text to '**Email Alert**' for enabling/disabling and '**Email Address**' where user will enter his/her id.

Also as @MiChAeLoKGB suggested, you can make email id text field visible only if alert is ON.

Better UX will be something like show in below image:
(Change title to '**Email Alert**' and gray-out email text if option is disabled.

[image]